# How to include tests with `skip_on_cran()` when calling `covr::package_coverage()`?

Tags: r, testthat, covr

I have a few tests with `skip_on_cran()` in a package. They will be run locally when I use call `devtools::test()`. However, when calling `covr::package_coverage()`, it does not run these tests. How to include these tests in the call to `covr::package_coverage()`?

To reproduce this problem. I created a test repository:

https://github.com/sfcheung/testcovr

This is a sample [test file](https://github.com/sfcheung/testcovr/blob/5fb7cde92f336d9f9cca3128b6c83d83528b3702/tests/testthat/test_foo.R)

```r
skip_on_cran()

test_that("Test foo", {
    expect_equal(foo(2), 4)
  })
```

`devtools::test()` correctly ran this test locally:

```r
> devtools::test()
ℹ Testing testcovr
✔ | F W S  OK | Context

⠏ |         0 | foo                                                                                                   
✔ |         1 | foo

══ Results ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[ FAIL 0 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 1 ]
```

However, `covr::package_coverage()` does not run that test:

```r
> covr::package_coverage()
testcovr Coverage: 0.00%
R/foo.R: 0.00%
```

I also tried to use `code` but it still did not run that test:

```r
> covr::package_coverage(type = "none", code = "devtools::test()")
testcovr Coverage: 0.00%
R/foo.R: 0.00%
```

Is there any way to run tests with `skip_on_cran()` when calling `covr::package_coverage()`?

Comment: Hi sfcheung, have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `NOT_CRAN` variable by executing

```
Sys.setenv(NOT_CRAN = "true")
```

and then calculate coverage as usual via

```
covr::package_coverage()
```